# Loadable Kernel Module logging problem in insmoding process

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules, c

I'm a beginner in `LKM` programming.

I was writing a simple argument passable module which gains command line arguments and then logs them in alert level.

The problem is that I don't know why it doesn't call the second `printk` in `hello_start` function, maybe an error had occurred there but the amazing thing is that it works in unloading(`rmmod`) process.
Here is logs and codes:

```
// insmod thetestmodule.ko yes_no=1
Dec 26 20:25:31 duckduck kernel: [  995.877225] Hi darcy. I'm now alive!
// Expect the argument here.

// rmmod thetestmodule
Dec 26 20:26:11 duckduck kernel: [  995.877230] This is the passed argument: 1
Dec 26 20:26:11 duckduck kernel: [ 1035.956640] Understood. Bye.
```

```
#include <linux/module.h>  
#include <linux/kernel.h>      
#include <linux/init.h>       
#include <linux/moduleparam.h>

#define AUTHOR "Darcy"

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL"); 
MODULE_AUTHOR(AUTHOR); 
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("OH. Kernel log, ALERT LEVEL O_o");
MODULE_VERSION("0.1"); 

static int short yes_no;
module_param(yes_no , short ,0);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(yes_no, "Enter 0 or 1 to say if you want the module be loaded in rescue mode.");

static int __init hello_start(void) 
{ 
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hi darcy. I\'m now alive!\n"); 
    printk(KERN_ALERT "This is the passed argument: %d" , yes_no); 
    return 0; 
} 
  
static void __exit hello_end(void) 
{ 
    printk(KERN_INFO "Understood. Bye.\n"); 
    return NULL;
} 
  
module_init(hello_start); 
module_exit(hello_end);
```

Thanks for your cooperation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second `printk()` does not have a `\n` at the end, while the first one has.

Also, the bracketed number after the word `kernel:` is the system uptime in seconds, so it looks like the second message was in fact generated well within the same second of time as the first one.

My first assumption is that the missing `\n` line terminator caused the process that was reading the kernel message buffer to wait in case more text was about to arrive, and the rest of the message was only processed by user-space logging daemon after the `\n` of the third message signaled that a complete line was received.

In the kernel message buffer (see the `dmesg` command) the bracketed uptime is typically the first element of the message: the human-readable timestamp, hostname and the word `kernel:` are added by whatever logging system was used to read the kernel message buffer and inject the kernel messages into the user-space logging stream(s).

So, try adding `\n` to the end of your second message, like this:

```
printk(KERN_ALERT "This is the passed argument: %d\n" , yes_no);
```